# Error uploading files thorugh php script

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having trouble in creating a php files upload script:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><h3>File: </h3> </label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Upload" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**upload_file.php:**

```
<?php
$restricted_extensions = array("htm", "html", "php", "asp", "aspx", "js");
$file_extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo("<h2>An error occured!</h2>");
    echo("<h2>Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</h2><br>");
}
elseif ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)
{
    $is_valid_extension = true;


    foreach ($restricted_extension as $extension => $value)
    {
        if ($file_extension == $extension)
        {
            $is_valid_extension == false;
        }

        if (!$is_valid_extension)
        {
            echo("<h2>The files extension " . $file_extension . " is not allowed!</h2>");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

**Error Messages:**

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 3

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: restricted_extension in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 15

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload_file.php on line 15

Comment: It seems that there is a part missing from upload_file.php. Please post the whole file to see where the problem is
[EDIT] Sorry - didn't scroll ;)

Comment: For last two  errors - you have a typo there (should be restricted_extensions instead of restricted_extension). Also, try to put `var_dump($_FILES); exit;` at the beginning of upload_file.php and show what you get after you try to upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce these errors, however you have a typo in naming of the variable $restricted_extensions. Mind the 's' at the end in the first line and the missing 's' at the end later in the code.

Since the error messages refer to unset Array keys, it seems that your upload does not work. Since your HTML Markup seems to be ok (and it works with my setup here), i suspect it to be some Server settings (Apache or what do you use?) or php.ini issue. Please check the relevant settings for allowing uploads.

Comment: I use Internet Information Services, I set everything up today, I think its all right

Answer (score -1):

The part on the end( explode()) thing.. u should first assign the explode() result to another variable and then passed that variable to the end() function  like so,

$variable = explode(somethig..);
$variable2 = end ($variable);

As for the other errors maybe this might help solve SOME of them..

Btw it worked for me and i dont have time to know why it was really a quick.at that time :)